# Pronunciation and meaning: "wind" and "wound"

Tags: etymology, verbs, nouns, pronunciation, history

I find it curious that there exist two words spelt *wind* ("a breeze" vs. "to turn") and two words spelt *wound* ("an injury" vs. the past participle of *wind*), and that the words in each pair are unrelated in etymology and are pronounced differently. Did these different pronunciations come about to differentiate between the meanings?

The OED says of *wound*:

> The original ŭ was normally lengthened before nd , but in the standard pronunciation has been prevented from developing into ou (as in bound , hound , ground , etc.) by the influence of the w (in contrast to wound , past tense of wind v.1). The pronunciation /waʊnd/ is however given by some dictionaries of the 18th century (Kenrick, 1733; Jones, 1798), is widely current in dialects, is implied in various forms of wounds int. and zounds int., and was common in the adverb woundy adj.1

How would the *w* prevent the /u/ from developing into /aʊ/, and why did it only affect one of the two *wound*s?

Comment: I take it that OED is not attributing the [theta role](http://www.sfu.ca/person/dearmond/322/322.theta.roles.htm) **agent** to the lowly 'w' ('If the participant ... has conscious control over something happening, the participant is called an agent), but rather perhaps **trigger** . Or perhaps we need a further class, _influencer_ (of an agent)? And once you introduce human choice, capriciousness and pragmatism into the equation, is any result surprising?

Comment: I had thought theta roles were part of syntax, not phonology. Or did I miss an in-joke? An initial /w/ is essentially a very short [u], and continues seamlessly into a nuclear [u] vowel, probably lengthening it. That doesn't necessarily "prevent" anything, but it's one more contributing factor to consider, like the great vowel shift, which has its exceptions, each of which is unique, and each of which has its own unique set of causes, many of which we will never understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sound /w/ had a large impact on the following vowel in the Great Vowel Shift. Consider: the  combination *war* should be pronounced like *car*, but usually is pronounced like *bore*—consider *warp*, *ward*, *warm*, *quarter*, *quarry*, *dwarf*. The combination *wor* should be pronounced like *bore*, but is usually pronounced like *burr*—consider *work*, *word*, *worship*, *worry*, *worm*, *worse*.

Why does /w/ have this effect? I have seen the explanation that you round your lips for /w/, and this means there is a tendency to round the following vowel as well. This explanation accounts for the different pronunciations of *wound* (as the OED says), but I don't believe it can account for *wind*, as the vowel is not rounded in either pronunciation of *wind*.

Why one of *wind* and *wound* was affected and the other wasn't is unclear, and is probably not the kind of question anybody can answer.