# Why is "wand" not pronounced simiarly to "hand" and "sand"?

Tags: pronunciation

Having a bit of a discussion about this with a friend.

The only reason I know to pronounce "wand" like "want" and not "hand" is because that's how I've heard it, and I've just copied that. But from a more rigirous point of view, I can't really explain *why* this is correct.

Is there any rule that applies to this?

Comment: It seems to be because of the "w". I think your question is answered here: [Why is the word watch pronounced differently from words like patch, latch, match, catch, and batch?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305023/why-is-the-word-watch-pronounced-differently-from-words-like-patch-latch-match)

Comment: Other related questions: [Sounds of the letter a](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7998), [The pronunciation of “was” has changed since the Seventeenth Century. When and why did it change"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174417),  [Pronunciation and meaning: “wind” and “wound”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/131165)

Comment: One could also ask: Why isn't _want_ pronounced like _pant, slant,_ or _rant_?

Comment: c. 1200, from Old Norse *vondr* "rod, switch" https://www.etymonline.com/word/wand

Comment: @Kris: Could you expand on what you mean by your comment? I might vote to re-open the question if I learn more about other possible explanations for the pronunciation of this word. Are you suggesting that the etymology indicates that the word *wand* was always pronounced with a rounded vowel? I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: The OED indicates that the rounded vowel in Old Norse *vǫndr* is the reflex of Proto-Germanic *a*. In older forms of English, we sometimes see variation between *a* and *o* before a nasal consonant, as in *land/lond.* So it seems possible to me that this word was taken into English with a variable vowel, *o* or *a,* and that the modern pronunciation with a rounded vowel comes from older *a.* Spellings of "wand" with "a" seem to go back to Middle English, which as far as I know is before the sound change that is responsible for the wa = /wɒ/ spelling correspondence of modern English.